# swift/parse getObjectInBackgroundWithId query not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to use the `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` method, of a `PFObject` and it throws this error:

```
"Cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type (string, block: (PFObject!,NSError?) -> Void"
```

I have written the below code:

```
var result = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    result.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("kk", block: {
        (object: PFObject, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        object["pLikes"] = object["pLikes"] + 1

        object.save()
    })
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` with

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("kk") { (objects, error) -> Void in

}
```

OR

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("kk") { (objects:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

}
```

Change the object

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("kk") { (objects, error) -> Void in
    let testObj = objects?.first as! PFObject
    testObj.setObject(26, forKey: "pLikes")
    testObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
        if succeeded {
            println("Object Uploaded")
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SotirisKaniras change value and save it

Comment: It worked! Actually, I removed the "let testObj = objects?.first as! PFObject" line, because it was causing an error and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @SotirisKaniras Welcome anytime :)